# why is everything white when i try to paint mesh?

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]
I created a mesh and  unwrap it. Then i  go to texture paint mode and choose diffuse but everything is white and i cant paint anything.

Comment: Select all the mesh in Edit mode and in the UV editor choose image you want to paint on.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a target texture for your paint information to go to.  You likely just need to add one (by clicking new texture in the UV/Image view) or choosing one (by click the texture dropdown in the UV/Image view).

I believe everything is white because that is your material diffuse color.